# How to get contain size width and height?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, viewport

Suppose I have the following html:

```
html,body{
    height: 100%;
    overflow-y: hidden;
}
div{
    background: url(path) no-repeat center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-size: contain;
}
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/J27fg/4/embedded/result/)

Here, the background-size is contain and is full width and height of 100% but the area of background image is not fully covered by the div.

**So, is there any way to get the width and height of the covered image?**

[image]

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15018068/get-the-size-of-background-image-with-jquery-after-containing-with-css

Comment: calculate the aspect ratio for the original height and width of the image, and then use the height/width of the div(whichever is smaller, I would think) and then calculate the new height and width for the contained image.

Comment: if you want dimensions of an image then use `<img>` element in `<div>` element. and then you can use javascript to get dimensions.

Comment: @SamyS.Rathore Could you please answer with an example?

Comment: @Mr_Green no, I cannot use.

Comment: @C-link I put my explaination into an example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Sourabh_Singh_Rathore/J27fg/10/embedded/result/)
for now, I have just used the height of the div, as it's smaller then it's width, but you actually got to check which one of them is smaller, as that would be the limiting factor to the background image stretching.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size) mentions the following about `contain`:

> This keyword specifies that the background image should be scaled to be as large as possible while ensuring both its dimensions are less than or equal to the corresponding dimensions of the background positioning area.

That would work out to the following code (ES6):

```js
function contain({width: imageWidth, height: imageHeight}, {width: areaWidth, height: areaHeight}) {
  const imageRatio = imageWidth / imageHeight;

  if (imageRatio >= areaWidth / areaHeight) {
    // longest edge is horizontal
    return {width: areaWidth, height: areaWidth / imageRatio};
  } else {
    // longest edge is vertical
    return {width: areaHeight * imageRatio, height: areaHeight};
  }
}

console.log(1, contain({width: 15, height: 60}, {width: 20, height: 50}));
console.log(2, contain({width: 15, height: 60}, {width: 50, height: 20}));
console.log(3, contain({width: 60, height: 15}, {width: 20, height: 50}));
console.log(4, contain({width: 60, height: 15}, {width: 50, height: 20}));
console.log(5, contain({width: 40, height: 20}, {width: 50, height: 20}));
```

Depending on the image orientation (portrait or landscape) it grows the longest edge first, then shrinks the shortest edge where necessary while still preserving the aspect ratio.

Comment: I just reviewed this and think there's something mistake, areaWidth may greater than imageWidth even in landscape mode but you are assigning imageWidth = areaWidth , is that correct??

Comment: I mean the initial size image is lesser width than viewport area when in landscape mode.

Comment: I mean areaWidth is 100% but imageWidth would not, right? If you are sure, could you please show me a demo?

Comment: I think I missunderstood. You mean areaWidth is viewport width or something else? If it is viewport width how can this be equal with imageWidth?

Comment: @C-link I mean that `areaWidth` is `$('div').width()`, i.e. the area is the block in which you have defined the background image.

Comment: So, the div's width is 100% and thus this is the viewport width, not? You can check my image in the question for clearer.

Comment: @C-link I suppose; again, I'm not sure what the problem is ... the definition of "contain" is expressed in that piece of code afaict.

Comment: areaWidth is to 100% so imageWidth never match, I think a demo will be clearer...

Comment: well a demo cleared me, you were doing right, but I couldn't figure out the equality get the width of the image width http://jsfiddle.net/J27fg/11/embedded/result/

Answer (score 0):

**Edit::**

```
var width = $('.demo').width(); //demo is div class name
var height = $('.demo').height();

// if width > height
var imgWidth = width > height ? actualImgWidth/actualImgHeight * height : width;
//if width < height
var imgHeight = height > width ? actualImgHeight/actualImgWidth * width : height;
```

Comment: that doesn't answer's the OP's question **So, is there any way to get the width and height of the covered image?**

Comment: if width > height then imgWidth is okay but what if width < height, something missing in your code.

Comment: in case of width < height, width will be the same but height is re-calculated by line:: var imgHeight = height > width ? actualImgHeight/actualImgWidth * width : height;

Answer (score 0):

Use below CSS :

```
div{
    background: url("Your Image Path") no-repeat;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: 100% auto;
  }
```